# Is this a valid implementation of a loop?

Tags: r

It seems like every question involving loops in R is met with "Loops are bad" and "You're doing it wrong" with advice to use `list`, or `tapply` or whatnot.

I'm learning R, and have implemented the following loop to create image files for each factor level, with the # of factor levels changing each time I run it:

```
for(i in unique(df$factor)) {
    lnam <- paste("test_", i, sep="")
    assign(lnam, subset(df, factor==i))
    lfile <- paste(lnam, ".png", sep="")
    png(file = lfile, bg="transparent")
        with(get(lnam), hist(x, main = paste("Histogram of x for ", i, " factor", sep="")))
    dev.off()
}
```

This works. I want to expand it to perhaps run various tests on those subgroups (also output to files), etc.

Is this a valid and legitimate use of loops? Or is there a preferred way to skin this cat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with loops in general. Sometimes, particularly when you're working with files or calling functions for their side-effects rather than their outputs, loops can be easier to follow than `*apply` calls. However, when you use a loop to simulate a operation that can be vectorised, it's often much slower, hence the recommendation to avoid them.

Re your specific example, though, I'd make the following comments:

- If you want to do something for each level in a factor, it's more straightforward to use `levels(factor)` rather than `unique(factor)`.
- You don't need to create a new data frame specifically for each factor level.

With that in mind:

```
for(i in levels(df$factor))
{
    lf <- paste("test_", i, ".png", sep="")
    png(file=lf, bg="transparent",
        with(subset(df, factor == i), hist(x, ....)
    dev.off()
}
```

Comment: You could also take the `paste` function outside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks - the simplifications make sense. Though I may be performing other "magic" on the produced data frames...  @csgillespie Your comment confuses me - How would you name the file then?

Comment: Something like `lf = paste("test_", levels(df$factor), ".png", sep=""`. Of course, you would need to change what `i` is iterating over. In this case, it doesn't make any difference which route you go down.

Comment: @Trees4theForest: if you want to do other stuff with each subset, just put the `with(subset(...` outside the call to `png`, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, a reasonable option is to use `split` to convert your data frame into a list of data frames, each containing subset of with a specific factor level.

```
split_df <- split(df, df$factor)
```

As Colin mentioned, `paste` can be vectorised, so you only need to call it once.

```
lfile <- paste("test_", names(split_df), ".png", sep = "")
```

Group all your plotting code into a function.

```
draw_and_save_histogram <- function(data, file)
{
  png(file)
  with(data, hist(x))
  dev.off()  
}
```

Now you can more easily compare the difference between a plain loop and an `*apply` function (in this case `mapply`, since we need two inputs).

```
for(i in seq_along(split_df))
{
  draw_and_save_histogram(split_df[[i]], lfile[i])
}

mapply(
  draw_and_save_histogram,
  split_df,      
  lfile      
)
```

---

Rather than drawing a lots of histograms to be saved in different files, it is much more preferable to draw one plot with several panels using `lattice` or `ggplot2`.

```
library(lattice)
histogram(~ x | factor, df)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ factor)
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the input. I was not aware of `split` - nice method. As for it being "more preferable to draw one plot" I guess that all depends on your needs. I am actually using lattice in the loop, drawing a series of nested plots, and need the inputs in separate files for the output. But it will be a nice lead for someone thinking they have the same question.